# 301 Redirect not behaving like I am wanting it too. What is my mistake?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, drupal

301 Wildcard. I don't think I am doing it right. Need `domain1.com/keyword5` to go to `domain2.com/keyword5`. Instead it does this:

`www.domain1.com/keyword5` goes to `www.domain2.com` (tld, root, not the keyword5 directory)

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain2\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

PS: Can I do multiple domains on the same .htaccess? For example, I have 3 domains on the same public_html, can I 301 each of them like this?

Comment: Your rule at a first glance seem ok to me, did you add `RewriteEngine on` before the rules in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: Regarding your "PS", yes you can!

Answer (score 1):

Your .htaccess actually looks OK-ish to me, in that it should work, although it can be simplified:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The RewriteRule substitution is a string, not a regex, so no need to escape everything. In fact you never need to escape forward slashes in .htaccess. No need for the double quotes either.